# Vue JS conditional rendering child component

Tags: conditional-statements, vuejs3

I am trying to render child components based on the user selection. I can do it very easily when in the parent component using v-if but when trying to render child components it is not working.

```
<template>

       <div class="mt-4">
          <p>{{ continents.asia }}</p>
          <p>{{ continents.africa }}</p>
          <ul class="space-y-8">
            <li>
                <button @click="showList('asia')">Asia</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button @click="showList('africa')">Africa</button>
            </li>
       </div>
        <div>
        <AsiaCountries v-if="continents.asia" />
        <AfricaCountries v-if="continents.africa" />
        </div>

</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import AsiaCountries from '@/components/Asia/AsiaCountries.vue'
import AfricaCountries from '@/components/AfricaCountries.vue'

const continents = {
    asia: ref(false),
    africa: ref(false),
    europe: ref(false)
};

const showList = (listName) => {
    for (const key in continents) {
        if (key === listName) {
            continents[key].value = true;
        } else {
            continents[key].value = false;
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

The `{{ continents.asia }}`is properly showing true when the button is clicked but the child component `AsiaCountries`is not rendered.

My child component AsiaCountries.vue :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Afghanistan</li>
            <li>Armenia</li>
            <li>Azerbaijan</li>
            <li>Bahrain</li>      
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

PS : In the console I get the following error: 'Extraneous non-props attributes (v-if) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use a usual (non-reactive) object with ref props. It's not unwrapped in `v-if` but unwrapped in the text interpolation inside `{{ }}` since it's the last part of the expression. The mechanism is described in the Vue's documentation:

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#caveat-when-unwrapping-in-templates

To make it work you should explicitly "dereference" the ref: `continents.asia.value`.

To avoid this (which looks ugly), convert your `continents` to a reactive object with usual props.

But the whole approach is too verbose, just use a simple string value to switch between continents:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
  <div class="mt-4">
    <p>{{ continent }}</p>
    <ul class="space-y-8">
      <li>
        <button @click="continent ='asia'">Asia</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button @click="continent = 'africa'">Africa</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <AsiaCountries v-if="continent === 'asia'" />
    <AfricaCountries v-if="continent === 'africa'" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import AsiaCountries from './AsiaCountries.vue'
import AfricaCountries from './AfricaCountries.vue'

const continent = ref('africa')
</script>
```

Further improvement would be avoiding separate components for continents and just build the list from JSON data filtered by a continent (use `computed`).

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer. I was thinking about working with JSON data but was wondering why this solution was not working. Got it now! Thanks again!

Comment: @sotizerie i've updated the answer. seems that's an expected Vue's behavior and described in the docs